# Efficiency of a solar cell

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, energy-harvesting, panel

I am from Colombia where recently was opened a solar park with a power of 61 MW [link to news](https://www.larepublica.co/economia/se-inauguro-el-parque-solar-san-fernando-el-autogenerador-mas-grande-del-pais-3251895)
I consulted the Solar radiation in the area and has a value of 5 kWh/m², the solar cell efficiency is 20%, the cell area is 2.5 m² and the power is 530 W peak.

My question is, if the solar radiation in 2.5 m² is 12500 Wh but the solar cell just convert 530 Wh does this means that the solar cell efficiency is around 4% far from 20%? Or how is measured the efficiency of a solar cell?

**EDIT:** [radiation data](http://atlas.ideam.gov.co/visorAtlasRadiacion.html)

Comment: Does Wp stand for watts peak? As in the maximum capacity of the cell rather than it's actual output power?

Comment: yes, it stands for watts peak i.e when the solar cell works on ideal conditions

Comment: I changed 'Wp' to 'W peak'. Sorry if that is incorrect but there is no SI unit 'Wp'.

Comment: I think you are well, just that the solar cell data sheet has Wp. But there is no SI Unit Wp

Comment: That "Solar radiation" of 5 kWh/m² is unclear, it says: 5 kWh, which is an amount of energy (18 MJ) per 1 m². What is missing is **time**. Is that 5 kWh/m² per second or per day or...? Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_irradiance

Comment: I think is per Hour

Comment: 5 kWh/h = 5 kW average **power**. (Notice that the 'h's cancel out. 5 kW x 1 h = 5 kWh (units of **energy**).

Comment: As far I know, the Sun irradiates 1100W/m^2 , it would be 1.1kWh of energy per hour for 1m^2, don't know about Columbia.

Comment: *I think is per Hour* Think again, if that were true I'd think we would all be roasted brown at the end of a sunny day. This planet would be like Venus: very hot indeed.

Comment: I add the radiation Data

Comment: Now try this map: https://globalsolaratlas.info/map?c=7.291639,-75.613403,7&s=8.971897,-74.564209&m=site  and note how you get around 5 kWh/m² **per day** or 2000 kWh/m² **per year**. Switch between day/year on the left.

Comment: now i understand you, so my data must be in kWh/day  so i need to divide by the number of solar radiation hours to get real kWh?

Comment: In my area I get about 1000 kWh/m² in a year, I have 29 m² of panels and they are 20 % effcient giving me 1000 kWh/m² * 29 m²* 20% = 5800 kWh/year which is about what I was expecting.

Comment: 5 kW/m^2 is not possible anywhere on earth from sunlight alone.

Comment: If you see solar energy in watt hours (as opposed to solar power in watts), they are referring to daily solar irradiation.  This is a logical unit, you don't care about how bright the sun is for a few minutes at noon, but how much energy you get per day.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič - Although the peak solar irradiance is about 1100W/m^2 it varies throughout the day - only the hour or two close to noon would be expected to reach that peak. That also assumes that the panel is normal to the incoming light for that to be true. If the panels are on fixed mounts then at other times or other times of the year the output power will be less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say,

> ... and the power is 530 W peak ...

and then say,

> ... but the solar cell just convert 530 Wh ...

so you have confused your units (W and Wh).

The Wh calculation is the average power output × the number of hours. Assuming a 10-hour useful day and, say, 250 W average output that would give us 250 × 10 = 2500 Wh. That's 20% of 12,500 Wh which makes sense.

---

Update after solar irradiation data added.

- The 5 kWh/m<sup>2</sup> appears to be for a 24 h day.
- 5 kWh/m<sup>2</sup> × 2.5 m<sup>2</sup> = 12.5 kWh per panel. (Your calculation is correct.)
- Assuming that the sun shines effectively for 10 hours per day that gives 1.25 kW average power irradiance per panel.
- If the panels' peak output is 530 W then the efficiency = \$ \frac {530}{1250} = 42.4\%\$.

It all seems to add up OK.

Comment: is just that the radiation data of the area is in kWh so if the solar cell has a power of 530 W is equivalent to say that converts 530 Wh. or am I wrong?

Comment: kW is a measure of **power**. kWh is a measure of **energy** which is **power x time**. 530 W for one hour = 530 Wh. 530 W for 2 hours = 1060 Wh.

Comment: yes but if the solar cell has a power of 530 W this does not mean that in a hour will produce 530 kWh Of Energy?

Comment: No. 530 W x 1 h = 530 **Wh**, not **kWh**.

Comment: sorry i confuse it , was a typo i mean Wh not kWh

Comment: i made a edit to add the radiation data

Comment: See the update.

Comment: While the units work out on this math, logically it doesn't make a lot of sense to use the peak (saturation) power of the panel to calculate efficiency, since at saturation (which hopefully doesn't occur very often), the panel is overloading and efficiency is plummeting.  To make an analogy this is like driving an amplifier into distortion and then measuring THD.  To calculate a more meaningful efficiency number, you would take the total energy produced divided by the total solar energy received.

Comment: could you explain deeper or give me reference of saturation effect you told please

Comment: @TFM, that wasn't me so you'll need to ping the user using `@username` syntax with no spaces - even if they're in the username.

Comment: @user1850479 *Since at saturation (which hopefully doesn't occur very often), the panel is overloading and efficiency is plummeting.* You don't miss much (a few %), check this video from the EEVBlog about this subject if you're interested: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4ER6I8Y9gA

Comment: @user1850479 could you please give us reference of saturation effect please

Comment: The effective Irradiance will not be constant thoughout the day. Your calculation assumes constant irradiance.

Comment: @Kevin, that's understood and I addressed that in the original answer. My answer is really addressing the OP's misunderstanding of power and energy and doing some order of magnitude checks. Feel free to write an answer that overlaps mine but gives more precise calculations.